# движение из точка а в точку б

Tags: java

я делаю игру на java и мне надо сделать пули, которая летит от башни к врагу вот мой код:

```
if (enemy_pos_x <= x) {
    x -= enemy_pos_x / flight_speed;

} else {
    x += enemy_pos_x / flight_speed;
}
if (enemy_pos_y <= t_pos_y) {
    y -= enemy_pos_y / flight_speed;
} else {
    y += enemy_pos_y / flight_speed;
}
```

но пуля летит просто вверх.
(этот код находится в таймере)
x=x позиция пули
y=y позиция пули
остальное понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ:

```
int vx = enemy_pos_x - t_pos_x;
int vy = enemy_pos_y - t_pos_y;
x += vx/flight_speed;
y += vy/flight_speed;
```

главная проблема, что пуля будет прилетать всегда с одинаковым временем.

Comment: Потому что вы опять секунды добавляете к метрам.

Answer (score 1):

Загадка: почему пуля летит вертикально? Ответ: потому что у пули не меняется `x`.

Загадка: почему не меняется `x`? Ответ: в правой части операторов присваивания нули.

Загадка: почему там нули? Ответ: такое может быть только если враг стоит в нуле (`enemy_pos_x = 0`). Или очень близко от нуля.

Получается что враги, которые забрались в ноль неуязвимы для пуль!

Как это исправить? Вспомнить школьную кинематику. Какую размерность имеет `enemy_pos_x`? Метры. А `flight_speed`? Метры в секунду. А если поделить? Секунды. А что дальше? А дальше вы прибавляете секунды к `x`, который в метрах.

С размерностями полная неразбериха. Чтобы это исправить нужно отделить координаты от скоростей, добавить время и записать кинематическую формулу для равномерного движения:

```
<новое положение пули> = <старое положение пули> +
    <скорость пули со знаком> * <промежуток времени между положениями>
```

Comment: я знал что враг стоит в нуле и это я понял через 5 мин после опубликования ответа